# Динамический массив (Java)

Tags: java

**Задача** : Массив состоит из натуральных чисел.

Количество элементов неизвестно,но если i-тый элемент массива будет == 0,то чтение элементов с клавиатуры прекращается и выводится максимальный элемент массива.

**Предисловие** : Не работал раньше с динамическим массивом ListArray

**Мой код** :

```
int rez = 1;
int max=0;
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.ensureCapacity(100);
System.out.println("Введите элементы");
while(!(rez==0)){
 int j;
    for (j = 0; j<b.size(); j++) {
        b.set(j, in.nextInt());
        if(!(b.get(j)==0)){
            if(b.get(j)>max){b.set(j, b.get(j));}
        }else{
            rez=0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
    System.out.println("Максимальный элемент вашего массива = " + max);
```

Comment: Мне говорили про то,что мол выход из цикла должен быть другим,но как не преобразовывал - бесполезно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот вам решение:

```
System.out.println("Введите элементы");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
while ((number = scanner.nextInt())!=0)
        numbers.add(number);

System.out.println("Максимальный элемент вашего массива = " + Collections.max(numbers));
```